# SQL display distinct record from the list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this set of result from table in MySQL:

Table example:

[image]

Is it possible if i want the result to be like this:

[image]

I only want one record for 'Aux Out: Answer Call', after 'Aux Out: Incoming Call'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code, others will extend your code based on your approach

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
with cte as
(
select row_number() over (partition by convert(varchar(10),TimeStamp,20),Activity  order by PK_EmployeeLog) as rid,* from @table
)
select * from cte where rid=1
```